# Make Search Results open in new tab

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, display-template

Ive implemented a SharePoint 2013 Farm Wide search for my site collections, and now want the URL's that get returned to open up in a new tab.

Is there a relatively effortless way to do this rather than messing with the display template, or is that the recommended way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

If this is for a search results webpart (like results.aspx), than what I found easiest was to add a content editor at the bottom of the page and add a little jquery to achieve this. You can use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ms-srch-item-link").attr("target","_blank");
</script>
```

This jquery will target all hyperlinks that appear in the search results webpart and change their attributes to open in a new tab. No messing with display templates.

Comment: 1) `$(".ms-srch-item-link").length` = 0.             
2) when paging in not firing. this code called just once on page load.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the default template rather easy - or you could add a jquery script to the search result page that handles the click event.

Answer (score 0):

add script editor webpart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted',".ms-srch-item-link",function(e){
         $(e.target).attr("target","_blank");
     })
 })
</script>
```

good for ajax paging of search results webpart